# DartPad allows string iteration

Tags: string, dart, iteration

I'd like to know why the code below prints each letter of `test` on **[DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ccd305a1b39d67159cc5)**, and throws an Exception on the **terminal**. I mean, Strings in Dart are not Iterable, so I don't understand how this works on DartPad; I'd expect an Exception there as well. Any ideias?

```
void main() {
  var test = 'test';
  for (var t in test) {
    print(t);
  }
}
```

*I tested this with Dart 1.14.0, but this was happening in previous versions as well.*

Comment: You need to use the "Share" feature to generate an unique URL for your DartPad. The link points to the default entry page.

Comment: I didn't intend to share my DartPad, but I guess it saves everyone some copy-paste. I'll update the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is because Dart is converted to JavaScript and JavaScript supports iterating over strings and probably for performance reasons there are no additional checks that prevent it.

What is IMHO a bug, is that the analyzer doesn't show a warning, even when `test` is explicitely typed as `String`

```
void main() {
  String test = 'test';
  for (var t in test) {
    print(t);
  }
}
```

When I enable strong-mode, I get a warning though.

`my_project/.analysis_options`

```
analyzer:
  strong-mode: true
```

> Type check failed: test (String) is not of type Iterable

for both

```
var test = 'test';
// or 
String test = 'test';
```

Comment: Even if the code is converted to JavaScript, this shouldn't happen. In my opinion, Dart and DartPad should behave in exactly the same way.

Comment: That's a nice wish ;-) The Dart team tries hard to come close but there are, as always, compromises to make, mostly for performance. Creating a bug report would be fine of course. Could be that this just slipped through.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. :)

Comment: [Reported here](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/issues/716), if anyone wants to follow.